# strapi - restrict user to delete/destroy only data related to him

Tags: strapi

I would like to write a few lines to prevent a user from deleting data he does not own.
How can I customize the following "destroy" part?

```
  destroy: async (ctx, next) => {
    return strapi.services.contactnumber.remove(ctx.params);
  }
```

Thanks in advance and happy easter.

Comment: P.S.: Add 
const user = ctx.state.user;
and...?

Comment: This feature is unfortunately restricted to enterprise version. You can tamper with the database directly in the table strapi-permissions or use wordpress :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've do the same for my app, please find below my example code :

```
findOne: async (ctx) => {
    var rent = await strapi.services.rent.fetch(ctx.params);
    var user = ctx.state.user;
    rent = rent.toJSON ? rent.toJSON() : rent;
    if (user.id === rent.tenant.user) {
      return rent;
    }
    else {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, 'Forbidden');
    }
  },
```

Maybe it's not the best implementation, but it's working fine :)
The keyword "await" is important, because you need to wait the full response before verify the response (otherwise "undefined" will be returned).

I think your code will looks like that :

```
destroy: async (ctx, next) => {
  var contactnumber = await strapi.services.contactnumber.findOne(ctx.params);
  contactnumber = (contactnumber.toJSON ? contactnumber.toJSON() : contactnumber);
  if (ctx.state.user.id === contactnumber.user) {
     return strapi.services.contactnumber.remove(ctx.params);
  }
  else {
     return ctx.badRequest(null, 'Your error message');
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @vanessa,
Where would we add this scripts in Strapi project code?